# Variable for dealing with multiple artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-delivery

In my release pipeline having Two artifacts.

```
Build
Tests
```

[image: Artifacts]

While selecting files under artifact I am using "Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias" and accessing the Build artifact files. but is there any variable we can use to access files under Test artifact.

I have tried with "Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias" but in Documentation only mentioned that for scheduled and manual releases this value will be empty.

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#general-artifact

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no Release Pipeline predefined variable to get the value of the required artifacts Source Alias(Name: Tests).

For a workaround, you can check the sources alias of the artifacts.

[image]

Then you can manually set the variable in Release Pipeline.

[image]

Then you can use the variable in Release Pipeline.